# Why is setting the window's RVC taking about 4 seconds?

Tags: ios

I'm stepping though the code interactively in XCode of my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method and have noticed that it is pausing for about 4 seconds at the last line in this pseudo code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

  ...
 create and initialize model
 ...
create UIViewController
create navController with view controller

self.window.rootViewController = navController;
```

Where navController is as its name implies a UINavigationController.

Why is it pausing at this particular line when stepping through using Xcode?

I'm initializing my model in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: and perhaps not coincidentally am testing the behavior when there are quite a lot of data objects for the model to scan upon creation (its scanning files, reading them and creating objects, so likely to be slow when there's lots of files). At the moment the model initialization is synchronous and  I'm seeing how long it takes to determine if it should become asynchronous and that's when I noticed this behavior.

If its the model which is taking time to construct and that is why I'm seeing the delay in the IDE then why is this delay manifesting when the rootViewController is being set and not when the model is constructed?

To clarify what my question is:

- I'm not asking why is my code slow
- I'm not asking how to track down the location of slow code
- What I am asking, merely because I am curious, is why if my model initialization is slow does it manifest when interactively stepping through the code in the debugger at the assignment to the window's RVC.

Comment: Are there other threads running? What are they doing?

Comment: No I'm not using any other threads

Comment: If you comment out that line, does it improve?

Answer (score 0):

Try [`Instruments`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) to track down issues like this.

Comment: Thanks but that's not my question. I'm not asking how to find out where time is consumed in iOS programs. I'm wondering out of curiosity and asking why when stepping through in the IDE it manifests at this line. If I come back to you and say instruments shows my model construction is slow, as I expect it will, my question still remains why does it manifest at this line when using the debugger.

Comment: Well, that line is just an assignment, so there is no problem there. Any slow code should be before that line or after it. Can you paste more code?

Comment: That's my whole point of my question. There is no problem with that line exactly, therefore I am curious why any previous slow code previously manifests as a delay at that point.